# connect с указателями в контейнере

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

При соединении с указателями, которые находятся внутри локального `map`, вылетает программа с ошибкой: `Segmentation fault`. Если сделаю мап статик или как поле, то все будет работать.

Вопрос: почему ломается коннект, если `map` хранит указатели на объекты, а не сами объекты? Какие решение есть, кроме как статик?

Вот пример, который смог сделать:
[image: Окно состоит их 7 проверочных кнопок и кнопки стоп]

someobj.h

```
#ifndef SOMEOBJ_H
#define SOMEOBJ_H

#include <QObject>
#include <QDebug>

class SomeObj : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit SomeObj(QObject *parent = nullptr) : QObject(parent) { }
public slots:
    void someSlot() { qDebug() << "someSlot"; }
};

#endif // SOMEOBJ_H
```

mainwindows.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H

#include <QMainWindow>
#include "someobj.h"

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}

class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = nullptr);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    SomeObj obj[7];
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"

#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMap<QPushButton *, SomeObj *> m {
        { ui->pushButton, &obj[0] },
        { ui->pushButton_2, &obj[1] },
        { ui->pushButton_3, &obj[2] },
        { ui->pushButton_4, &obj[3] },
        { ui->pushButton_5, &obj[4] },
        { ui->pushButton_6, &obj[5] },
        { ui->pushButton_7, &obj[6] }
    };
    for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
        connect( it.key(), &QPushButton::clicked, [=] () {
            it.value()->someSlot();
            qDebug() << it.key()->objectName();
            ui->btnStop->setEnabled(true);
        });
    }
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

---

**UPD1:** а почему нельзя вызвать `sender()` в анонимной функции?

---

**UPD2:** При раскомменчивании любой строчки программа вылетает.

```
for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {
    connect( it.key(), &QPushButton::clicked, [=, obj = it.value(), btn = it.key()] () {
//            obj->someSlot();                      //  #1
//            qDebug() << sender()->objectName();   //  #2
        qDebug() << obj->objectName();          // работает
        qDebug() << btn->objectName();          // работает
        ui->btnStop->setEnabled(true);
    });
}
```

---

**UPD3:**
При попытке:

```
connect( it.key(), &QPushButton::clicked, [obj = it.value(), btn = it.key(), ui] () {...
```

вылетает ошибка `'ui' in capture list does not name a variable`. Поэтому так:

```
connect( it.key(), &QPushButton::clicked, [obj = it.value(), btn = it.key(), uii = ui] () {
//        obj->someSlot();                      //  #1
//        qDebug() << sender()->objectName();   //  #2
    qDebug() << obj->objectName();          // работает
    qDebug() << btn->objectName();          // работает
    uii->btnStop->setEnabled(true);
});
```

И так, уже функция sender() не видна, тк this не передается. Но почему при раскомменчивании `#1` программа вылетает?

---

**UPD4:** все договариваю. Могу проект скинуть. Класс `SomeObj` не изменял.Конструктор MainWindow изменил так:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    QMap<QPushButton *, SomeObj *> m {
        { ui->pushButton, &obj[0] },
        { ui->pushButton_2, &obj[1] },
        { ui->pushButton_3, &obj[2] },
        { ui->pushButton_4, &obj[3] },
        { ui->pushButton_5, &obj[4] },
        { ui->pushButton_6, &obj[5] },
        { ui->pushButton_7, &obj[6] }
    };
    for (auto it = m.begin(); it != m.end(); ++it) {

        connect( it.key(), &QPushButton::clicked, [obj = it.value(), btn = it.key(), btnS = this->ui->btnStop] () {
//            obj->someSlot();                      //  #1
//            qDebug() << sender()->objectName();   //  #2
            qDebug() << obj->objectName();          // работает
            qDebug() << btn->objectName();          // работает
            btnS->setEnabled(true);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Так объект `m` выходит из области видимости

Comment: да, и правда.. а какое решение посоветуете? и почему нельзя вызвать `sender()`?

Comment: Можно перенести объявление `map` в хидер, так он не будет выходить из области видимости. К тому же вы сможете его использовать и в других методах `MainWindow`

Comment: `sender()` должен работать в лямбде

Comment: Что такое "анонимная функция"?

Comment: @AnT имеется в виду лямбда. Не догадались?

Comment: Вопрос "почему нельзя вызвать sender()?" звучит как "почему у велосипеда квадратные колеса?". Как вы пытаетесь вызывать свой `sender()`? Где пример вашего вызова? Почему он не приведен в вопросе?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Теоретически" ваш `map` хранит *указатели* на интересующие вас объекты и в правильно написанном коде время жизни самого `map` не должно влиять на работоспособность вашего кода. Однако вы написали вашу лямбда-функцию так, что она занимается захватом *итераторов* этого `map` и всю работу делает через эти итераторы. В такой ситуации, как только `map` прекращает свое существование, попытки доступа через её итераторы приводят к падению программы.

Прекратите захватывать итераторы и перепишите свою лямбду так, чтобы она захватывала значения указателей `it.key()` и `it.value()` и далее работала именно через захваченные указатели, а не через итератор. Таким образом вы полностью отвяжете вашу лямбду от этого временного `map`

```
[=, obj = it.key(), button = it.value()] () 
{
    obj->someSlot();
    qDebug() << button->objectName();
    ui->btnStop->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Более того, при создании долгоживущих лямбд я бы посоветовал вам не пользоваться механизмом неявного захвата. Лучше прописывайте все захваты явно, чтобы отдавать себе отчет в том, что именно вы захватываете и к каким последствиям это может привести

```
[obj = it.key(), button = it.value(), ui = this->ui] () 
{
    obj->someSlot();
    qDebug() << button->objectName();
    ui->btnStop->setEnabled(true);
}
```

Comment: у меня остался только вопрос: почему не работают #1, #2?

Comment: @KtoTo Вы что-то недоговариваете. Работает `obj->objectName();`, но не работает `obj->someSlot()`?? Вы что-то еще поменяли.

Comment: обновил. Если в лямбду не передавать `this`, понимаю что `sender` вызвать нельзя. Если передавать, при вызове `sender` программа вылетает

Comment: можно ли отдельно ф-цию передать в квадратных скобках: `[send = this->sender] () {...}`?